# seeking solution to avoid multiple execution of linux commands in php script

Tags: php, bash, shell

I have a PHP script which provides some output to angular. That script is useful to get the informations from the Perl script. I'm using `exec()` command to call the scripts in PHP.I'm getting whatever i want but the problem is time-consuming. I executing the same script thrice to create the array in php. ex:

```
exec("/usr/bin/reports -h -r -t ".$this->name." | grep -o '^\S*' | sed '1 d'",$report_id);
exec("/usr/bin/reports -h -r -t ".$this->name." | grep -oP '(?<= ).*' | sed '1 d'",$titles);
exec("/usr/bin/reports -h -r -n ".$this->name." | grep -oP '(?<= ).*' | sed '1 d'",$fullnames);
```

as you can see I'm executing the same script multiple times only because changing parameter.
by first command I'm storing report_id, second command to store their position and third is for their full names. I need a solution to comprise these three commands into one. please help to avoid the time complexity

Sample output

```
exec("/usr/bin/reports -h -r -t ".$this->name."); 

user1     Full name       DIRECTOR.OPERATIONS
user2     Full name       COLLEGE INTERN.TECH UNDERGRAD
user3   Full name     COLLEGE INTERN.TECH UNDERGRAD
user4      Full name            COLLEGE INTERN.TECH UNDERGRAD
user5   Full name COLLEGE INTERN.TECH GRAD
user6      Full name          PROGRAM MANAGER.PROJECT/PROGRAM MGMT
```

Comment: Execute the script once and put the results in a PHP variable. All the stuff you're doing with `grep` and `sed` can be done in PHP.

Comment: hello Barmer thanks for the quick response. I will edit this post with sample output, then will discuss about the regex in php

Comment: Tip: As you both are users with some reputation consider a discussion with [StackOverflow's chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110148/how-to-chat-in-stack-overflow) and share with us only with conclusion pls :)

Comment: I thought of spliting with spaces but unfortunatly those spaces are not predictable, It will differ based on their names and the positions

Comment: you could even run the report once, put the whole thing in variable and still use the unix grep with syntax like $value=\`echo $output | grep "pattern"\`. A dirty trick but will save code complexity. if it's just running the report that is your concern. I do it like this all the time.

Comment: Hi Gary, could you plz elaborate on the pattern here :). I'm trying this for past two days

Comment: Why are you using the same `grep` command for `$titles` and `$fullnames`?

Comment: Are you sure it's spaces and not tabs between the fields?

Answer (score 0):

Put the output of the `/usr/bin/reports` command into an array, then process the array with PHP code instead of `grep` and `sed`.

```
$output = [];
exec("/usr/bin/reports -h -r -t ".escapeshellarg($this->name), $output);
$report_id = [];
$titles = [];
$fullnames = [];
unset($output[0]); // skip first line
foreach ($output as $line) {
    $fields = explode("\t", $line); // I'm guessing those are tab separators
    $report_id[] = $fields[0];
    $fullnames[] = $fields[1];
    $titles[] = $fields[2];
}
```

Comment: Will test it Barmer.. sounds like it is space only, let me check

Comment: If there's no reliable way to tell which spaces are between fields or inside fields, it will be hard to automate this.

Comment: It is not separated by tabs.

Comment: Then how can you tell the difference between a space in the full name and the space separating the name from the title? Is `George Walker Bush Pilot` a person named `George Walker` whose title is `Bush Pilot`, or `George Walker Bush` with title `Pilot`?

Comment: yes exactly that's where I'm struggling. { abk aroon tricky software enginner/management } here abk->user-id aroon tricky->fullName software enginner/management->title . I'm thinking is there any way to split the array with linux command parameter .

Comment: If it's ambiguous, there's no reliable way to parse it. Maybe you should see if there's a way to get the information you need without having to parse command output that's intended for humans rather than computers.

Comment: Can you modify the perl script so it has an option to output a CSV or JSON?